# Batch file is not getting executed in jenkin pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am having jenkin Jenkins 2.289.1, at I am converting the existing job to the pipeline.
The same batch which is working in job but is not working in pipeline.
Even when the batch file does not exist, no error thrown but task ended as completed.
Any idea on the issue?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'RELEASE', choices: ['860', '859', '858','857'], description: 'Pick something')
        string(name: 'SrcTestSetNameToCopy', defaultValue: '', description: 'Source ALM test Set Name')
        string(name: 'TestSetNameToBeCreated', defaultValue: '', description: 'Test Set Name to create')
        choice(name: 'Platform', choices: ['ORACLE', 'MICROSFT', 'DB2ODBC'], description: 'Pick something')
        string(name: 'BuildOverride', defaultValue: '', description: '4 dit build overwrite value')
        choice(name: 'EnvnBuildType', choices: ['DEP', 'QAE'], description: 'Pick something')
        booleanParam(name: 'TOGGLE', defaultValue: true, description: 'Toggle this value')

       
    }
    stages {
        
        stage('Create ALM Test Set') {
            steps {
               
               
               // bat "\"C:\\JenKin_Jobs\\Test.bat\""
               // bat 'C:/JenKin_Jobs/Test1.bat'
               // bat 'wmic computersystem get name'
               //bat 'echo %PATH%'
               echo 'selva'
                echo "Current workspace is $WORKSPACE"
                
               //bat returnStatus: true, script: 'C:\\JenKin_Jobs\\Test.bat'
               bat script: 'C:\\JenKin_Jobs\\Test.bat'
               
                
                
               
            }
        }
         
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found an workaround - but this works in one set of box but not on the another- Any idea. In some box, it looks, the batch itself not executed because will not thrown error if batch is not there. Hence looks some setting is missing between the 2 boxes. Any idea ? path varaiable has cme.exe path in both boxes

Answer (score 0):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                // below simple echo executed
                echo 'Hello World'
               
                //bat 'C:\\JenKin_Jobs\\NetUSeIDrive.bat'
                bat 'cmd.exe "/c C:\\JenKin_Jobs\\NetUSeIDrive.bat" '
               
                bat 'cmd.exe /c c:\\JenKin_Jobs\\SQAClnUp.bat "I:\\\\***\\\\SQA_CONFIG_FILES\\\\859 Stuff\\\\@@@@\\\\P05\\\\P05B"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The pipeline works in one set of box but not in another? IS there any config missing between the boxes. Both are usins same jenkin version